# Shifting from animate to fadeIn

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein

Good Morning,

I have copied this code from somewere

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    setInterval("rotateImages()", 200);
    });

    function rotateImages() {
        var oCurPhoto = $('#lb2Animate div.current');
        var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
        if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0) 
        oNxtPhoto = $('#lb2Animate div:first');
        oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300,
            function() {
                oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
            });
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">


#lb2Animate {
position:relative;
float:left;
height:126px;
width:131px;
margin-left: auto;
}
#lb2Animate div {
position:absolute;
z-index: 0;
}
#lb2Animate div.previous {
z-index: 1;
}
#lb2Animate div.current {
z-index: 2;
}

</style>
```

What i need to do is to move from animate to fadeIn
i need to change the animate in here:

```
oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300,
            function() {
                oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
            });
```

Can i get any help

im not so familiar with jQuery

Thanks in advance.
good day

Comment: Change the function name from "animate" to "fadeIn" and delete the first parameter.

Comment: Man i tried but its not working !!!

Comment: The reason that simply changing animate to `fadeIn()` doesn't work is because it needs that the element to be faded have CSS display property set to none, not just opacity 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 300,
    function() {
        oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
});
```

to

```
oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').fadeIn(300, function() {
    oNxtPhoto.removeClass('previous');
});
```

I would look at refactoring that further, perhaps look at the [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) or some of the [tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on the jQuery website to get started. It isn't much of a learning curve, especially if you are familiar with Javascript.

---

**Edit**: It won't work just by changing it to fadeIn, because that won't affect the opacity css change. You might want to change it to:

```
oNxtPhoto.hide().addClass('current').fadeIn(300, function() {
    oNxtPhoto.removeClass('previous');
});
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FsRSQ/1/**

Comment: Might want to remove the  initial .css() that sets the opacity, or replace it with .hide()?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            setInterval("rotateImages()", 2000);
        });
        function rotateImages() {
            var oCurPhoto = $('#photoShow div.current');
            var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
            if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
                oNxtPhoto = $('#photoShow div:first');
            oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
            oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current').animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000,
                function() {
 oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
});
}
    </script>

Comment: You will need to get ride of the `.css({ opacity: 0.0 })` and replace it with `.hide()`

Comment: <style type="text/css">
#photoShow {
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
}
#photoShow div {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}
#photoShow div.previous {
    z-index: 1;
}
#photoShow div.current {
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>

Comment: ok my friend , now it works, but still have the same effect like before , what i want to do is get the effect of fadein

Comment: It is fading in, do you just mean slower? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FsRSQ/2/ 

or this: http://jsfiddle.net/FsRSQ/3/

Comment: can u take a look to this jsFiddle ?    jsfiddle.net/rolandfeghaly/Jxhxf/6/

Comment: I really appreciate ur help , thank u man, but this is what i was getting before, and still my manager dont want it , what he wants is so get fadein slowly so this animation wont be like slides, he wants it to be like only one fade in from 0 --> 1.0 , u understand what i need , maybe we can use fadeTo ????

Comment: You will just need to use `clearInterval()` to stop the loop. http://jsfiddle.net/Jxhxf/10/

Comment: Sorry for my bad english , what i want is when the slide ends, wait for 2 seconds and then restart , but thats not my problem , my problem is the slides , if u look u can see that these slides are acting like stripes or curtain , i need to get them fade in so i wont have this effect , i need to get them like if it was on flash, one animation not like stripes, its like when u use fade from 0 to 1.0  in 4 seconds, it will fade from light to 100%, i hope u understand me , thank u dear friend

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12233/discussion-between-roland-and-n1ck)